# Odoo 10 Sales > Pipeline - rearrange view icons

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

[image]

Hi ,it is Odoo 10E

I find I am very difficult to figure out how to re-arrange the view icons below. I want the **default view as List view** instead of Kanban view.

I have tried both Studio, Edit Action, Modifying crm_lead_views.xml but it still does not work. I am afraid there may be something wrong I have not been aware of.

In fact, when it is in Kanban view and creating a new opportunity, the default form is too simple. I must have a default creating form in a comprehensive form (that is why I want the List view). If there is a way to change the Create button in Kanban that directs to a comprehensive opportunity creation form, that also solve my issue.

thank you for attention.

Comment: did you try to change the view_mode in the action?

Comment: no idea of this. do you mean i should change something in Technical > Actions ?  If so, what should I do?  I actually have tried Edit Action > Your Pipeline> General Settings > View mode   but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a coincidence, i've stumbled upon the same problem yesterday...

The dashboard buttons - e.g. "My Pipeline" - work with a server action which calls `crm.team`'s `action_your_pipeline()`.

To change it, you have to override this method. I will share my code:

```py
from odoo import api, models


class CrmTeam(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.team'

    @api.model
    def action_your_pipeline(self):
        """ overridden to change the views order"""
        action = super(CrmTeam, self).action_your_pipeline()
        tree_view_id = self.env.ref('crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor').id
        form_view_id = self.env.ref('crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor').id
        kanb_view_id = self.env.ref('crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads').id
        action['views'] = [
            [tree_view_id, 'tree'],
            [form_view_id, 'form'],
            [kanb_view_id, 'kanban'],
            [False, 'graph'],
            [False, 'calendar'],
            [False, 'pivot']
        ]
        return action
```

Comment: it is not easy to figure out this. Thanks a lot CZ. I know why many says Odoo is difficult to many techs.

Comment: No problems. Could you please mark this answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

In the crm_lead_menu.xml you can find the ir.actions. You need to override the action:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_external_id">
    ...
    <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,graph,pivot,form,calendar</field> <!--Put the views the order you want-->
    ...        
</record>
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: yes, we have changed the file /addons/crm/views/crm_lead_views.xml  and must ensure restart odoo and load the update. But it doesn't work. I just wonder there is another code that overrides this change. But I have no idea why.

Comment: That is indeed the correct answer if we're talking about simple window actions. But don't forget the action views order at the bottom of the action formular ;-)